# How to make vertical space between paragraphs without affecting the TOC and Headings?

Tags: paragraphs, vertical-spacing

If I use `\setlength{\parskip}{1em}` it does exactly what I need but it messes up my headlines and the spacing between the items in the table of contents as well. Is there something that only creates the spacing between actual text paragraphs?[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em} 

{\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\tableofcontents}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But note that the space above sections in ToC is not due only to a  `\parskip` of 1em. To avoid any vertical skip you can use this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`parskip`](https://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package is doing exactly what you want. Load it with `\usepackage[skip=1em,indent,parfill]{parskip}`. The first option is setting `\parskip` to be `1em`, the `indent` option keeps the indent of the document class (if this option is not specified, the indent is set to zero) and the last option adjusts \parfillskip.

For example, compare the following documents

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parskip}{5em} % settings \parskip to 5em just to exaggerate the effect 
    
    {\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
        \tableofcontents}
    
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[skip=5em,indent,parfill]{parskip}
\begin{document}
    
        \tableofcontents
    
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

As can be seen, in the second document not only the spaces in the toc is not affected, but also the the ones surrounding sectioning headings.